# Flex box equal height rows

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve the following layout with flexbox

[image: desired layout]

My markup is as follows:

```
<!-- first col -->
<div class="l-col">
  <div class="l-wrap">
    <div class="l-row l-row--brand">
      row
    </div>
    <div class="l-row">
      row
    </div>
    <div class="l-row">
      row
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- second col -->
<div class="l-col">
  <div class="l-wrap">
    <div class="l-row l-row--brand">
      row
    </div>
    <div class="l-row">
      row
    </div>
    <div class="l-row">
      row
    </div>
    <div class="l-row">
      row
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen example
http://codepen.io/magicspon/pen/doyKYW

Bare minimal code used.

Each row should be the same height.

The markup needs to stay the same, or a least the use of columns with rows inside needs to remain.

Any thoughts? If I can do this without using JavaScript and fixed heights I'd be super happy.

UPDATE
Overall layout, the final two columns are the ones mentioned above
(note, i've had to clear out the content as this is for a secret project)
[image: Full layout]

Comment: If you give .l-row a fixed height, I believe this should work as you expect. If you're not trying to use fixed heights, how would you want the height of each row determined?

Comment: Hello, the two columns sit with a few other columns within a flex container.  So each column is the same height.  Within the two final columns, I want each sub-row (l-row) to have an equal height.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe you can be more clear about what the heights of these rows should be.

Comment: @magicspon I don't get why you use flex box if you seperate them in different columns.

Comment: So do you want each of those white boxes (on the right) heights to be determined by the tallest of the boxes? Sorry - I'm just having trouble understanding.

Comment: each of the white boxes in the final two columns should be the same height.  I'm starting to think that this isn't going to be possible, as the column with three white boxes has no way of knowing the height of the rows in the final column. hmm!

Comment: There are ways to make those white boxes to be the same height, maybe not in the way you are thinking though... For example, here is a percentage based solution... but it would require you to at least know how many rows were possible. You could also set fixed heights here...

http://codepen.io/theleggett/pen/QbWxMR